# Can I cache partially-executed LINQ queries?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, double>> items =
    sequence.Select(item => new KeyValuePair<T, double>(item, weight(item)));
if (items.Any(pair => pair.Value<0))
    throw new ArgumentException("Item weights cannot be less than zero.");

double sum = items.Sum(pair => pair.Value);
foreach (KeyValuePair<T, double> pair in items) {...}
```

Where `weight` is a `Func<T, double>`.

The problem is I want `weight` to be executed as few times as possible. This means it should be executed at most once for each item. I could achieve this by saving it to an array. However, if any weight returns a negative value, I don't want to continue execution.

Is there any way to accomplish this easily within the LINQ framework?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure, that's totally doable:

```
public static Func<A, double> ThrowIfNegative<A, double>(this Func<A, double> f)
{
    return a=>
    { 
      double r = f(a);  
      // if r is NaN then this will throw.
      if ( !(r >= 0.0) )
        throw new Exception(); 
      return r;
    };
}

public static Func<A, R> Memoize<A, R>(this Func<A, R> f)
{
    var d = new Dictionary<A, R>();
    return a=>
    {
        R r;
        if (!d.TryGetValue(a, out r))
        {
          r = f(a);
          d.Add(a, r);
        }
        return r;
    };
}
```

And now...

```
Func<T, double> weight = whatever;
weight = weight.ThrowIfNegative().Memoize();
```

and you're done.

Comment: Why? Memoization is the correct term for this concept: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: @L.B: OK, what name would you prefer for a *function memoizer*?

Comment: @EricLippert I don't think any of the answers are within the LINQ framework (the original question). If, on the other hand, Memoize() was already part of LINQ, then THAT (imho) would be the answer to the OP's question. I think your answer should begin with, "No, but you can extend the functionality in this way:" Perhaps this isn't the literal intent of the OP.

Comment: i never thought about chaining extension methods on Funcs before (although i bet i've used them) - i'm having trouble understanding the purpose of the `T` in `Func<T, double> weight = whatever;`

Comment: The `ThrowIfNegative` idea is what I really need. Then I can just call `.ToArray()`, as I don't quite need `Memoize`. @AaronAnodide The `T` is the type parameter present in my original code.

Comment: Why are you checking if `!(r >= 0.0)`? Wouldn't `< 0.0` come to the same result, since even with double's floating point behavior, it should still be unambiguous? Or is floating point math even a problem for such checks? (Genuinely curious)

Comment: @MichaelStum Checking equality against NaN is difficult because it's not equal to anything, including itself. It is neither less than, greater than or equal to zero, it is simply not a number. In Eric's code, checking the reverse will include NaN because it is clearly not greater than or equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to move the exception into the `weight` function, or at least simulate doing so, by doing something like:

```
Func<T, double> weightWithCheck = i =>
    {
        double result = weight(i);
        if (result < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Item weights cannot be less than zero.");
        }
        return result;
    };

IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, double>> items =
    sequence.Select(item => new KeyValuePair<T, double>(item, weightWithCheck(item)));

double sum = items.Sum(pair => pair.Value);
```

By this point, if there is an exception to be had, you should have it.  You do have to enumerate `items` before you can be assured of getting the exception, though, but once you get it, you will not call `weight` again.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are good (where to throw the exception, and memoizing the function).

But your real problem is that your LINQ expression is evaluated every time you use it, unless you force it to evaluate and store as a List (or similar). Just change this:

`sequence.Select(item => new KeyValuePair<T, double>(item, weight(item)));`

To this:

`sequence.Select(item => new KeyValuePair<T, double>(item, weight(item))).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do it with a foreach loop. Here is a way to do it in one statement:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, double>> items = sequence
    .Select(item => new KeyValuePair<T, double>(item, weight(item)))
    .Select(kvp =>
    {
        if (kvp.Value < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Item weights cannot be less than zero.");
        else
            return kvp;
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing already **IN** the LINQ framework to do this, but you could surely write up your own methods and invoke them from the linq query (As has already been shown by many).

Personally, I would either `ToList` the first query or use Eric's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a functional memoization suggested by other answers, you can also employ a memoization for the whole data sequence:

```
var items = sequence
    .Select(item => new KeyValuePair<T, double>(item, weight(item)))
    .Memoize();
```

(Note a call to `Memoize()` method at the end of the expression above)

A nice property of data memoization is that it represents a drop-in replacement for `ToList()` or `ToArray()` approaches.

The fully featured implementation is pretty involved though:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

static class MemoizationExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Memoize all elements of a sequence, e.g. ensure that every element of a sequence is retrieved only once.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The resulting sequence is not thread safe.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the elements of source.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">The source sequence.</param>
    /// <returns>The sequence that fully replicates the source with all elements being memoized.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> Memoize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) => Memoize(source, false);

    /// <summary>
    /// Memoize all elements of a sequence, e.g. ensure that every element of a sequence is retrieved only once.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the elements of source.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">The source sequence.</param>
    /// <param name="isThreadSafe">Indicates whether resulting sequence is thread safe.</param>
    /// <returns>The sequence that fully replicates the source with all elements being memoized.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> Memoize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, bool isThreadSafe)
    {
        switch (source)
        {
            case null:
                return null;

            case CachedEnumerable<T> existingCachedEnumerable:
                if (!isThreadSafe || existingCachedEnumerable is ThreadSafeCachedEnumerable<T>)
                {
                    // The source is already memoized with compatible parameters.
                    return existingCachedEnumerable;
                }
                break;

            case IList<T> _:
            case IReadOnlyList<T> _:
            case string _:
                // Given source types are intrinsically memoized by their nature.
                return source;
        }

        if (isThreadSafe)
            return new ThreadSafeCachedEnumerable<T>(source);
        else
            return new CachedEnumerable<T>(source);
    }

    class CachedEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>
    {
        public CachedEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            _Source = source;
        }

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        IEnumerable<T> _Source;

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        IEnumerator<T> _SourceEnumerator;

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        protected readonly IList<T> Cache = new List<T>();

        public virtual int Count
        {
            get
            {
                while (_TryCacheElementNoLock()) ;
                return Cache.Count;
            }
        }

        bool _TryCacheElementNoLock()
        {
            if (_SourceEnumerator == null && _Source != null)
            {
                _SourceEnumerator = _Source.GetEnumerator();
                _Source = null;
            }

            if (_SourceEnumerator == null)
            {
                // Source enumerator already reached the end.
                return false;
            }
            else if (_SourceEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                Cache.Add(_SourceEnumerator.Current);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Source enumerator has reached the end, so it is no longer needed.
                _SourceEnumerator.Dispose();
                _SourceEnumerator = null;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public virtual T this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                _EnsureItemIsCachedNoLock(index);
                return Cache[index];
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => new CachedEnumerator<T>(this);

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

        internal virtual bool EnsureItemIsCached(int index) => _EnsureItemIsCachedNoLock(index);

        bool _EnsureItemIsCachedNoLock(int index)
        {
            while (Cache.Count <= index)
            {
                if (!_TryCacheElementNoLock())
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        internal virtual T GetCacheItem(int index) => Cache[index];
    }

    sealed class ThreadSafeCachedEnumerable<T> : CachedEnumerable<T>
    {
        public ThreadSafeCachedEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> source) :
            base(source)
        {
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                lock (Cache)
                    return base.Count;
            }
        }

        public override T this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                lock (Cache)
                    return base[index];
            }
        }

        internal override bool EnsureItemIsCached(int index)
        {
            lock (Cache)
                return base.EnsureItemIsCached(index);
        }

        internal override T GetCacheItem(int index)
        {
            lock (Cache)
                return base.GetCacheItem(index);
        }
    }

    sealed class CachedEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        CachedEnumerable<T> _CachedEnumerable;

        const int InitialIndex = -1;
        const int EofIndex = -2;

        int _Index = InitialIndex;

        public CachedEnumerator(CachedEnumerable<T> cachedEnumerable)
        {
            _CachedEnumerable = cachedEnumerable;
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get
            {
                var cachedEnumerable = _CachedEnumerable;
                if (cachedEnumerable == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();

                var index = _Index;
                if (index < 0)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();

                return cachedEnumerable.GetCacheItem(index);
            }
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _CachedEnumerable = null;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            var cachedEnumerable = _CachedEnumerable;
            if (cachedEnumerable == null)
            {
                // Disposed.
                return false;
            }

            if (_Index == EofIndex)
                return false;

            _Index++;
            if (!cachedEnumerable.EnsureItemIsCached(_Index))
            {
                _Index = EofIndex;
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _Index = InitialIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

More info and a readily available NuGet package: https://github.com/gapotchenko/Gapotchenko.FX/tree/master/Source/Gapotchenko.FX.Linq#memoize